# Why did Haman make both a lottery AND gallows to reach the 50th gate?

Tags: torah-study, mysticism-kabbalah, purim

BH

It says in the [Maamer Al Kayn Karoo, 5750](https://chabadlibrary.org/books/admur/mlukat/3/11/index.htm) that Haman [harasha] knew that according to Seder Histalshiloos, he would have no chance to [chos vishlom] win over the Yidden, since Seder Histalshiloos favor Tzadikim, and all of the people of Yisroel are Tzadikim, so he tried to make a lottery, in order to reach beyond Seder Histalshiloos, as explained at length there, but the basic idea is that relative to a lottery, all options are equal, since if one object had an advantage over the other [even if one only *wants* one over the other] there's no need to make a lottery, and in spiritual terms, that refers to a level that's beyond Seder Histalshiloos, which, relative to that "Like darkness, Like light"

Anyways, after exlaining how even according to that level, the "free choice" of the Essence of Hashem anyways chooses the people of Yisroel, it says that this  is also related to why he made the gallows 50 amos, in order to reach the "50th gate" of Bina [see Ramban introduction to Bereshis], then it says that, relative to that level, "darkness is like light", and it adds in the parenthesis, that the 50th gate is the same spiritual level that's the "lottery" [last page]:

ועד"ז הוא בנוגע להעץ אשר הכין לו72, לו לעצמו73, דהטעם שעשה עץ גבוה חמישים אמה הוא74 כי רצה להגיע לשער הנו"ן שלמעלה מהשתלשלות ששם הוא כחשיכה כאורה, והנס דפורים הי' שגם מצד הדרגא דלמעלה מהשתלשלות **(גורל, שער הנו"ן)** תלו את המן על העץ, ואז נתגלה שגם זה שהכין העץ מלכתחילה הי' לו, לעצמו.

---

(bold emphasis mine, which translates to "Lottery, 50th gate", in effect saying they are the same)

So if Haman Harasha was anyways able to reach the 50th gate through the lottery alone, why did he need to specifically make the gallows 50 amos high?

Comment: In case, for whatever reason, his lottery method was ineffective?

Comment: @ClintEastwood interesting idea.. yea its possible, although from earlier in the maamer it seems to say that even just through the lottery he would have reached there [if not for Hashem's essential choice in the people of Yisroyayl], and I'm not sure what would be added with the gallows, regarding G-d's essential choice etc., unless I'm missing something